# Disable Safe Area insets for UIViewController inside UIScrollView. (TikTok-like vertical feed)

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, uikit

I want to build a TikTok-like vertical CollectionView in which each cell is an UIViewController.

I'm having issues with managing safe area insets in those content View Controllers.
Since they are inside the scroll view, I don't want their safe-area insets to update as their change their position.

I've tried "disabling" safe area insets on some view by overriding `safeAreaInsets` property and returning zero insets.

```
// In my subclass of UICollectionViewCell
// MyCell.swift
override var safeAreaInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
    .zero
}
```

However, it doesn't always work - especially when I add another UIViewController's view inside that view.

Here's the video that demonstrates the issue: [Video link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sgv9slo2kezgtg8/bug.MP4?dl=0)

What is the best way to control safe area insets in scroll views?
Is there any way to force UIView/UIViewController to have specific safe area insets that doesn't change as the view is changing its position (and going beneath the iPhones notch)?